# Thin out pathway in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to thin out the google 'G'. Ive tried by hand and ended up with very mediocre results. Is there a way in Inkscape that allows selected a pathway and then having the path thin out.

For example a function that moves nodes tangentially to the curves they lie on toward the next point that would be found along the path in the direction of the tangent.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. I am having a hard time understanding what you want: 1) Do you have an outline path and want to make it thinner? 2) Do you want to reduce the number of nodes on a simple path? 3) Something else. — Please [edit] your question to clarify, preferably with a sketch.

Comment: Yes I was trying to take for example what would be the bold google 'G' and reduce it to a normal non-bold 'G'. I ended up using a method very similar to the answer by Billy Kerr.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I've understood your question properly, then yes there is a way to do it.

I assume the letter is already a path. If it's still editable type, then convert it to outlines first by using *Path > Object to Path*.

Next, remove the fill, and add a stroke, then adjust the weight of the stroke in the Fill and Stroke panel, so that the white internal space is as thin as you want the letter form to be.

Click *Path > Stroke to Path*

Click *Path > Break Apart*

Select the outer path and delete it, leaving the inner path only.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Billy understood you right, but from the 2nd paragraph, you might have something like this in mind:

[image: Character outlines with nodes]

Make the character a path, if it isn't already. Select node mode (emphasized with green mega dots here), select the end nodes, where the shape shall be thinned out, and delete them with the node deletion button in the toolbar, for instance.

Only the inner tangential will determine, how to tighten the path, since the outer one is directing outwards.

Comment: Im not steady enough to get a good result this way